# Family access to Thai Airways international lounges in Bangkok

Tags: children, bangkok, lounges, bkk

I'm a Star Alliance Gold member and may be passing through Bangkok Suvarnabhumi Airport (BKK) with family in the near future.  Standard Star Alliance rules permit only one guest per cardholder, end of story; however, member airlines are often more liberal, sometimes as a [matter of policy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135988/as-singapore-airlines-krisflyer-gold-can-i-bring-my-family-into-the-lounge-on) and [sometimes in practice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139394/access-to-star-alliance-gold-lounges-at-singapore-with-children) even when policy says something different.

For Thai Airways, the only source I can find is [this undated page on their Australia site](https://www.thaiairways.com/en_AU/offer/special_offers/loungepasses.page#:%7E:text=For%20THAI%27s%20Royal%20Orchid%20Lounges,rates%20apply%20for%20older%20children.), which says children under 6 get free access and anybody else can pay "from A$76" for access.  Is this still the case in 2022?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had the opportunity to test this out today, and long story short, Thai Airways does indeed stick to the one guest limit.  However!

- Children under 6 are free, and
- Additional guests can purchase access for 1300 THB (~US$40)

In our case they let two kids in for the price of one extra guest, bringing the cost down to a rather reasonable US$20/child, so two thumbs up to Thai.  [Singapore Airlines](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/139394/access-to-star-alliance-gold-lounges-at-singapore-with-children), are you listening?

...although I have to note that of all the varied food offerings in the lounge, both offspring said their favorite was the Mama cup noodles. Given that these retail for around 12 baht a pop, you'd need to eat 100 portions to pay off the guest fee!

Comment: Singapore Airlines only starts listening after a 3-hour wait on their customer support phone line.

Comment: +1 for Mama cup

Answer (score 2):

Lounge availability during Covid period may change without notice. So please plan ahead.

As a matter of policy you can bring one guest. Period. You may try your luck at entrance maybe you are lucky. If not you can try King Power lounge which is accessible to member. You can apply by top up your account for 2,000 Baht and use that credit to purchase things at their shops at airport.

> (1.2) Royal Silk Lounge and Royal Orchid Lounge:
>
> Present a boarding pass of THAI Royal Silk Class – no guest allowed
>
> Present a boarding pass of Star Alliance Business Class travelers – no guest allowed
>
> THAI Royal Orchid Platinum and Gold members presenting a boarding pass of THAI or any Star Alliance flight.  One guest is allowed when departing on the same day of THAI or Star Alliance flights.
>
> THAI Royal Orchid Platinum and Gold members presenting a boarding pass of Thai Smile Airways. One guest is allowed when departing on the same day of THAI or Thai Smile Airways.
>
> Star Alliance Gold status cardholders presenting a boarding pass of THAI or any Star Alliance flight. One guest is allowed when departing same day on the same day of THAI or Star Alliance flights.
>
> Star Alliance Gold status cardholder presenting a boarding pass of Star Connecting partner and a connecting itinerary of a Star Alliance flight. One guest is allowed when departing on the same flight with Star Alliance Gold passenger.
>
> Any accompanying person over the age of two is considered a guest. Children under the age of two may accompany the customer to the lounge and are not considered as guests.

https://www.thaiairways.com/en/experience_my_thai/on_ground/Lounge_Policy.page

Comment: Thanks. So they are no longer offering the option of paying for additional guests?

Comment: Not sure about TG lounge but others do. I saw it was about 30-40 USD per person. You have to check again when you reach BKK.